# Converting JavaScript timestamp formatted as Sat Dec 30 1899 HH:MM:SS to today?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

I have an application which presents shift start and finish times as a javascript Date where the date is set as Sat Dec 30 1899 with the appropriate start/finish time:

```js
const start = new Date(-2209139100000); // Sat Dec 30 1899 06:15:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
const finish = new Date(-2209095900000); // Sat Dec 30 1899 18:15:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

My application is sent these times dynamically as part of a json object. I don't have access to the main server which the times are coming from so I am unable to correct them at source.

What I am trying to do is convert the shift start time to today's date (and appropriate shift start time) and then the finishing time to the appropriate time in the future. When my application receives the times the shift start time will have always passed (within previous 12 hours). Shifts can pass over midnight (night shifts) but shift lengths can vary (6, 8, 10 and 12hours) but shifts will always conclude within 24hours of the start time.

Could someone give me some pointers or a starting point please?

Comment: So you just want the hours?

Comment: I need a the full date time as I need to perform comparisons (i.e if the shift has finished).

For example the start time above would need to be Tuesday Dec 15 2020 06:15:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time) and then the returned finish time would be the appropriate time in the future.

Comment: So how did you get from december 30 to 15?

Comment: @Rojo because that's today's date?

Comment: Sat Dec 30 1899 is I believe some sort of Microsoft base date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Date` method [`setUTCFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCFullYear) to change just the date part of a `Date` instance. Then simply add the original time difference to the new start date to get the new finish.

```js
const start = new Date(-2209095900000);
const finish = new Date(-2209052700000);
console.log("Original start:", start.toISOString())
console.log("Original finish:", finish.toISOString())

const diff = finish - start
const now = new Date()

// Clone start
const newStart = new Date(start)

// Set date part to today
newStart.setUTCFullYear(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate())

// Set finish to be the same diff from newStart
const newFinish = new Date(newStart.valueOf() + diff)

console.log("Start:", newStart.toISOString())
console.log("Finish:", newFinish.toISOString())
```

Comment: Perfect this looks like something I will be able to work with.

Comment: @JonathanAdams I've altered my answer a little with what I think is a better approach

Comment: this is appreciated. I cant get my head around how to get it to work with shifts passing midnight. For example if you use the times start = `-2209095900000` and finish = `-2209139100000` it returns `Start: 2020-12-15T18:15:00.000Z
Finish: 2020-12-15T06:15:00.000Z` where as the finish should be `2020-12-16T06:15:00.000Z`

Comment: @JonathanAdams the code in my answer uses a night-shift example and it works as expected

Comment: @JonathanAdams `2209139100000` is `1899-12-30T06:15:00.000Z` which is before your _start_

Comment: I think *all* the dates are on Dec 30 even if it is a night shift.

Comment: @pilchard seems OP has figured out how to [make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65298944/283366). That's some real crappy data

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have settled with which seems to be working:

```js
const now = new Date();
const start = new Date(-2209095900000);
const finish = new Date(-2209139100000);

const newStart = new Date(start);
newStart.setUTCFullYear(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate());

const newFinish = new Date(finish);
newFinish.setUTCFullYear(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), (start > finish) ? now.getUTCDate() + 1 : now.getUTCDate());

console.log("Original Start:", start.toISOString())
console.log("Original Finish:", finish.toISOString())
console.log("New Start:", newStart.toISOString())
console.log("New Finish:", newFinish.toISOString())
```

Comment: Nicely done. Given the state of your initial data, I'd say this is the best way forward

Answer (score 0):

You can do this arithmetically by creating a new date from the sum of the original `start` date and the difference in days between `Date.now()` and that date. The new finish date can then be created by adding the difference between the original `start` and `finish` dates to the new start date.

```js
const 
  start = new Date(-2209095900000),  // 1899-12-30T18:15:00.000Z
  finish = new Date(-2209139100000); // 1899-12-30T06:15:00.000Z
  
let
  shiftTime = finish-start;
  // if start is later than finish add a day
  if (shiftTime < 0) shiftTime += 8.64e7;
 
const  
  startVal = start.valueOf(),
  dayDiff = (Math.floor(Date.now()/8.64e7)-Math.floor(startVal/8.64e7))*8.64e7,
  newStartVal = startVal + dayDiff;
   
const
  newStart = new Date(newStartVal),
  newFinish = new Date(newStartVal+shiftTime);
  
console.log('Start');
console.log('old: ', start);
console.log('new: ', newStart);  
console.log('Finish');
console.log('old: ', finish);
console.log('new: ', newFinish);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to work out the number of whole days from *start* to now and add that many days to both start and finish, e.g.

```js
function fixDates(start, finish) {
  // Start of current UTC day
  let now = new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
  // Start of start UTC day
  let s = new Date(start).setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);

  // Whole UTC days difference
  let diff = (now - s) / 8.64e7;
  // Add to start and finish
  start.setUTCDate(start.getUTCDate() + diff);
  finish.setUTCDate(finish.getUTCDate() + diff); 
  return [start, finish];
}

// Examples
[[-2209139100000, -2209095900000],
 [-2209095900000, -2209139100000]].forEach(arr => {
   let s = new Date(arr[0]);
   let f = new Date(arr[1]);
   console.log('Start : ' + s.toLocaleString());
   console.log('Finish: ' + f.toLocaleString());
   console.log('Fixed');
   let [sf, ff] = fixDates(s, f);   
   console.log('New start : ' + sf.toLocaleString());
   console.log('New finish: ' + ff.toLocaleString());
 })
```

There are always exactly 8.64e7 ms in an ECMAScript UTC day, so daylight saving has no effect. Adding days by adding to the date also avoids DST effects.